# SELECT the customer who has ordered the greatest quantity of Products in the case of two customers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following ORDERS table

[image]

I know query to select the customer that has ordered the greatest quantity. However, how would it work, if say, two customers have the same quantity. What query should I write to show both the customers?

Comment: `select * from Customers where qty=(select max(qty) from Customers)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery which checks that the quantity for a given record matches the largest quantity observed in the table:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE qty = (SELECT MAX(qty) FROM yourTable)
```

This will return multiple records if there are more than one customer sharing the maximum quantity.

If you only wanted to get back a single record, even in the presence of ties, you could use this approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY qty DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want sum of qty per custNum.

If so you can try like:

```
select custNum,
    sum(qty) as qty
  from Orders 
  group by custNum
  order by sum(qty) desc;
```

**Fiddle here:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47931b/10

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT custnum,sum(qty) as total
FROM orders
group by custnum
having sum(qty) = (SELECT MAX(qty) FROM orders);
```

This will return both values.